# PostgreSQL Equivalent command for Database "Take Offline" and "Bring Online"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to disable database for few hour everyday.

In MSSQL server we have an option to disable and enable database through Take Offline/ Bring Online Command.

[image]

I want the same option in PostgreSQL as well.Please let us know any
similar command or option to do this.

Comment: This can not be done through SQL (or some GUI). The best option is probably to change [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) to prevent all remote logins then reload the configuration (`select pg_reload_conf();`)

Comment: Another option - if you don't need to do anything with that database otherwise - is to completely disable connections to that (one) database: `alter database ... with ALLOW_CONNECTIONS  = false;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your support. Please  let us know that Superadmin can access the Database after execute the alter database query.

Comment: No one can access the database if you disallow connections. If you still need to connect to the database (e.g. through the superuser), you need to change `pg_hba.conf`